# msyql replication time

Tags: linux, mysql, mysql-replication

I am planning to setup mysql master-master or master-slave configuration. Yet to be decided.

But my question is, is there any way to specify in the slave or master saying that it needs to check for master's binary file every say, 5 seconds or so ? Is this parameter configurable ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Do you want to enforce a delay in replication between the master and the slave?  Are you looking to configure the reconnect time?  I think you might be misunderstanding MySQL replication - the slave I/O thread maintains a persistent connection to the master.  It doesn't poll it periodically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 5.6, you can do it with [MASTER_DELAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html) option.

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_DELAY = 5;
```